# Are there any websites from which we cannot fetch network-images for flutter projects?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, networkimageview

Any websites which does not allow or limit their network images to be shared in flutter?

Comment: it depends on each website - look at their license / terms of use etc. Most will not appreciate you sharing their data without permission.

Comment: any website that might give error or null image if used?

Comment: And also if you submit to AppStore it will we asked you if you have agreement from data you use or display in your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think any website has currently limited their data by the technology that tries to access it.

However, all images are the property of their owners and the fact that they offer you a limited license to view them on their pages does not mean you are allowed to redistribute them in your own content.

It does not make much sense either, since http://example.com/dog.jpg might show a dog today, but might show a cat or a copyright warning tomorrow. You are not in control of that content, so using it in your app is pointless.

You should use images that you have a license for. Either because you paid for them, or maybe because generous people have pictures with licenses that allow you to redistribute them and use them as your own under certain conditions (for example many require mentioning in the credits, which seems to be a very small price to pay).

Flutter itself has a system to automatically generate such a license page for you if you are using resources that require it: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/LicensePage-class.html

So to sum it up: do not use other pages data without their explicit consent. That includes images.